# Clarification of output of metabin and metareg

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I used the *metabin* and *metareg* commands in the *meta* package of R.
There were 21 trials and I initially looked at the safety outcome.  The output of *metabin* is below.

```
Test of heterogeneity:

      Q    d.f.  p-value
  35.72      20   0.0166

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Mantel-Haenszel method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
```

Below is the output of  *metareg* with vaiables "TypeRCT" which takes a value of a 1 or a zero, "Per" which goes from 30-100, and "Rec" ranging in values from 250 to 422.  Output of metareg below

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 21; tau^2 estimator: DL)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0168 (SE = 0.0722)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.1294
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 7.97%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.09
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            86.59%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 17) = 18.4732, p-val = 0.3596

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3,4): 
QM(df = 3) = 13.7827, p-val = 0.0032

Model Results:

         estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
intrcpt   -0.5573  0.8053  -0.6920  0.4889  -2.1358  1.0211   
TypeRCT    0.1144  0.2415   0.4737  0.6357  -0.3590  0.5878   
Per       -0.0115  0.0062  -1.8497  0.0644  -0.0237  0.0007  .
Rec        0.0032  0.0018   1.7514  0.0799  -0.0004  0.0068  .
```

My question is does the QM  of 13.7827 and p-val of 0.0032 mean that the variables together account for significant portion of heterogeneity.  Second question: Do the p-values of 0.06 and 0.08 mean that the estimates of coefficients are not quite significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question: Correct. The test is an omnibus test of the null hypothesis that the true coefficients for `TypeRCT`, `Per`, and `Rec` are all jointly equal to 0 (in which case your model does not explain any heterogeneity). Clearly, you can reject that null hypothesis.

Regarding the second question: Correct. It may be somewhat surprising that the omnibus test is significant, but none of the individual coefficients reach significance (at $\alpha = .05$). This usually indicates that the predictor variables are correlated (i.e., there is some degree of multicollinearity).